# What does nvprof output: "No kernels were profiled" mean, and how to fix it

Tags: cuda

I have recently installed Cuda on my arch-Linux machine through the system's package manager, and I have been trying to test whether or not it is working by running a simple vector addition program.

I simply copy-paste the code from [this tutorial](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/) (Both the one using one and more kernels) into a file titled `cuda_test.cu` and run

```
> nvcc cuda_test.cu -o cuda_test
```

In either case, the program can run, and I get no errors (both as in the program doesn't crash and the output is that there were no errors). But when I try to run the Cuda profiler on the program:

```
> sudo nvprof ./cuda_test
```

I get result:

```
==3201== NVPROF is profiling process 3201, command: ./cuda_test
Max error: 0
==3201== Profiling application: ./cuda_test
==3201== Profiling result:
No kernels were profiled.
No API activities were profiled.
==3201== Warning: Some profiling data are not recorded. Make sure cudaProfilerStop() or cuProfilerStop() is called before application exit to flush profile data.
```

The latter warning is not my main problem or the topic of my question, my problem is the message saying that No Kernels were profiled and no API activities were profiled.

Does this mean that the program was run entirely on my CPU? or is it an error in nvprof?

I have found a discussion about the same error [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/988289/cuda-programming-and-performance/nvprof-error-on-samples/), but there the answer was that the wrong version of Cuda was installed, and in my case, the version installed is the latest version installed through the systems package manager ([Version 10.1.243-1](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/cuda/))

Is there any way I can get either nvprof to display the expected output?

## Edit

Trying to adhere to the warning at the end does not solve the problem:

Adding call to `cudaProfilerStop()` (or `cuProfilerStop()`), and also adding   `cudaDeviceReset();` at end as suggested and linking the appropriate library (`cuda_profiler_api.h` or `cudaProfiler.h`) and compiling with

```
> nvcc cuda_test.cu -o cuda_test -lcuda
```

Yields a program which can still run, but which, when uppon which nvprof is run, returns:

```
==12558== NVPROF is profiling process 12558, command: ./cuda_test
Max error: 0
==12558== Profiling application: ./cuda_test
==12558== Profiling result:
No kernels were profiled.
No API activities were profiled.
==12558== Warning: Some profiling data are not recorded. Make sure cudaProfilerStop() or cuProfilerStop() is called before application exit to flush profile data.
======== Error: Application received signal 139
```

This has not solved the original problem, and has in fact created a new error; the same happens when `cudaProfilerStop()` is used on its own or alongside `cuProfilerStop()` and `cudaDeviceReset();`

## The code

The code is, as mentioned copied from a tutorial to test if Cuda is working, though I also have included calls to `cudaProfilerStop()` and `cudaDeviceReset()`; for clarity, it is here included:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <math.h>

#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>

// Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays

__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  int index = threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x;
  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
      y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}


int main(void)

{

  int N = 1<<20;

  float *x, *y;


  cudaProfilerStart();


  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU

  cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));

  cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));



  // initialize x and y arrays on the host

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    x[i] = 1.0f;

    y[i] = 2.0f;

  }



  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU

    add<<<1, 1>>>(N, x, y);



  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();



  // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)

  float maxError = 0.0f;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)

    maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f));

  std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;



  // Free memory

  cudaFree(x);

  cudaFree(y);
  
  cudaDeviceReset();
  cudaProfilerStop();

  

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: That last warning is the main problem. You need to flush profiling data, either using a *ProfilerStop call, or cudaDeviceReset before your application exits. This is clearly discussed in the documentation (assuming your GPU is supported by nvprof, the latest generation are not, this is also described in the release notes)

Comment: @talonmies no, that doesn't work see edit

Comment: The reason the suggesting didn't work was that there was another problem with the calling of the profiler -- although the error code after adding the suggested lines were the key to finding the problem -- see answer below

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This problem was apparently somewhat well known, after some searching I found [this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1010691/visual-profiler/nvprof-error-code-139-but-memcheck-ok/) about the error-code in the edited version; the solution as discussed there is to call nvprof with the flag --unified-memory-profiling off:

```
> sudo nvprof --unified-memory-profiling off ./cuda_test
```

This makes nvprof work as expected-- even without the call to cudaProfileStop.

Comment: In my case, I still get "No kernels were profiled.".nvprof --unified-memory-profiling off aos_soa.exe
==18560== NVPROF is profiling process 18560, command: aos_soa.exe
==18560== Profiling application: aos_soa.exe
==18560== Profiling result:
No kernels were profiled.
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
      API calls:   84.05%  217.08ms         1  217.08ms  217.08ms  217.08ms  cudaMalloc

Comment: Using ```--unified-memory-profiling off``` avoids indeed the error, but that's not the solution (rather a workaround). Does anybody know why unified memory can't be profiled using ```nvprof``` and what the solution to this is?

Comment: @geohei According to the book Professional CUDA Programming you can indeed profile them using unified memory, You just have to put `--unified-memory-profiling per-process-device `

Comment: @KansaiRobot It doesn't work on CUDA 10.2, I still get "No kernels were profiled."

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by using

```
sudo nvprof --unified-memory-profiling per-process-device  <your program>
```

Comment: "per-process-device" gives runtime but no detailed information vs "off"

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe not enable `GPU performance counters`.

When i enable it in windows GPU driver, the issue is solved at WSL.

Comment: How does one enable this? Can you [edit] your answer to include instructions?