# nvprof - Warning: No profile data collected

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

On attempting to use `nvprof` to profile my program, I receive the following output with no other information:

```
<program output>
======== Warning: No profile data collected.
```

The code used follows this classic [first cuda program](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/even-easier-introduction-cuda/). I have had nvprof work on my system before, however I recently had to re-install cuda.

I have attempted to follow the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611689/what-does-nvprof-output-no-kernels-were-profiled-mean-and-how-to-fix-it) which suggested to include `cudaDeviceReset()` and `cudaProfilerStart/Stop()` and to use some extra profiling flags `nvprof --unified-memory-profiling off` without luck.

[This nvidia developer forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/warning-no-profile-data-collected-nvprof-not-working-when-compiling/178105) post seems to run into a similar error, however the suggestions here seemed to indicate needing to use a different compiler than `nvcc` due to some OpenACC library I do not use.

### System Specifications

- System: Windows 11 x64 using WSL2
- CPU: i7 8750H
- GPU: gtx 1050 ti
- CUDA Version: 11.8

For completeness, I have included my program code, though I imagine it has more to due with my system:

Compiling:

```
nvcc add.cu -o add_cuda
```

Profiling:

```
nvprof ./add_cuda
```

add.cu:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>

// function to add the elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
  int N = 1<<20; // 1M elements

  cudaProfilerStart();

  // Allocate Unified Memory -- accessible from CPU or GPU
  float *x, *y;
  cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));

  // initialize x and y arrays on the host
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
  add<<<1, 1>>>(N, x, y);

  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
  float maxError = 0.0f;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f));
  std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

  // Free memory
  cudaFree(x);
  cudaFree(y);

  cudaDeviceReset();
  cudaProfilerStop();

  return 0;
}
```

How can I resolve this to get actual profiling information using `nvprof`?

Comment: what happens if you run your code with `compute-sanitizer`? Are any errors reported? What GPU are you running on? What CUDA version?

Comment: I have included my system specifications in the question above. I get 0 errors running with compute-sanitizer

Comment: Profiling is not yet supported on wsl2 https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#support-matrix-for-wsl2

Comment: That’s unfortunate to see. Definitely should have read the docs, ha! Thank you for giving me a conclusive answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#features-not-yet-supported), there is currently no profiling support in CUDA for WSL. This is why there is no profiling data collected when you are using nvprof.